# How can I create indexer and skillset for language studio custom question and answering?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I need to use azure cognitive search for my project. I want questions and answers from a document,so I decided to use language studio's custom question and answering.

Now, the language studio automatically creates its own index, without any indexer. So I am not sure how I can add additional information to it like other skills to that index. For example, I also need the position where the answer is found in the document. I am not really sure how I can combine these two things.

Is there a way to define my own index, indexer and skillset for language studio so that I can have other fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its possible within language studio, but there is a sample for working with QnA and Azure Cognitive Search that actually creates an indexer for you called [the Search QnA Maker Accelerator](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-qna-maker-accelerator). Its a bit out of date but it may help you get started with the workflow you need. You could in theory fork this sample, edit the provided details under [Assets](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-qna-maker-accelerator/tree/main/CustomSkillForDataIngestion/QnAIntegrationCustomSkill/Assets) to add the skills and indexer configuration you want, and then deploy from your fork to use those updated object definitions.